# Как изменить цвет меню в WPF?

Tags: wpf, menu

Здравствуйте, подскажите начинающему, как можно поменять цвет меню со стандартного на другой, в данном случае хочу чтоб цвет был серым. Ставить бэкграунд на пунктах меню не вариант, т.к. цветом закрашивается только прямоугольник с текстом и между пунктами меню остаются полосы стандартного цвета.
Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже что ответ уже дан тут: [How to set foreground and background colors on a WPF Menu control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783705/how-to-set-foreground-and-background-colors-on-a-wpf-menu-control)